# a:hover background with img inside

Tags: html, css

When I mouse over linked images I see hover background color beneath the image. How to avoid this?

Is there any solution that would not involve applying special class to `a` elements (like `a.nobackground:hover`)?

CSS:

```
a:hover, a:focus {
    background-color: rgb(240,39,96);
    cursor: pointer;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" title=""><img src="with_transparency.png" alt=""/></a>
```

**edit:**
setting img background to none doesn't work

```
a img {
    background: none !important;
}
```

setting img background to any other color would do the job if there's no non-solid color (or graphic) beneath the image (in this case .png)

```
a img {
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does setting the background color of the images do what you want?

```
a img {
    background: none;
}
```

Depending on your stylesheets, you might need the `!important` bang in front of "none" to overwrite other conditions.

Edit: On second thought, you might want to explicitly set a color value instead of simply saying "none."

Another edit:  True, if the color or background behind the transparent PNG wasn't a solid color, you'll encounter some issues. One alternative is this:

```
<a href="#" class="transparent_png"></a>
```

And the CSS:

```
.transparent_png {
    background-image: url('with_transparency.png');
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    width: ??px;
    height: ??px;
}
```

So here, you're not actually using an image tag, but can overwrite the background-color property that's normally applied on a:hover and a:active. Does this work?

Comment: but you must remember to add display: block to .transparent_png and give it height and width

Comment: Ah, thank you... Silly me. If "block" display becomes an issue in your design, Memke, you can try inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly... You will need to either apply a special class to that specific link, or call the link by its location if it´s different from others. For example:

```
div div div a {}
```

And as Matt said you might need to use !important because you have a rule that includes all the links in the page. I´d recommend a different class, it´s better from a semantic´s point of view.